# What is in ~/Library/SOM?

Tags: library

I scanned my disk to find stuff to delete with Disk Inventory X. I am mystified by this directory, ~/Library/SOM. It's really big and all the files are *.tmp. Any idea?
[image]

Comment: [Related thread on /r/mac](https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/s9sg8/found_an_enormous_file_in_my_library_folder_not/c4cbw1x/), is that comment relevant to you?

Comment: @grgarside yes its the same thing and that they didn't solve it either. I noticed "f2" which I wonder if it has to do with Facebook somehow?

Comment: I think I figured it out: "Screencast-o-matic" -- SOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be detritus from "Screencast-O-Matic" an otherwise nice applications. For me it was over 70Gig!